# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, zipfile

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projetcs\python\discordTgr\tokengrabber\2test.py", line 6, in <module>
    zf.write(dirname)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

```py
import os
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w").extractall(pwd='P4$$W0rd') 
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("Spammer"):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
```

Comment: Думаю, не нужно присваивать `zf` результат выполнения функции `extractall` :)

Comment: В переменную zf записывается то что возвращает метод extractall, а он ничего не возвращает (просто распаковывает архив), поэтому в переменную записывается None.

Comment: а как тогда? можете изменить код, я вас просто не понял

Comment: Если вам нужно добавить файл/директорию в архив, вам не нужно ничего распаковывать, нужно вызывать write от объекта ZipFile.

Comment: досих пор не понял

Comment: Вообще уберите вызов метода extractall. Если нужно указать пароль, открывайте архив через ZipFile.open, пароль укажите как параметр этого метода. См. https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import os
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w")
zf.extractall(pwd='P4$$W0rd') 
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("Spammer"):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Это означает, что extractall ничего не возвращает. В документации написано, что что-бы записать что-то в архив надо обращаться к объекту типа ZipFile.

Пример из документации:

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('eggs.txt')
```

Если не понимаете что такое with : `ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w').write('eggs.txt')`

Если нужно создать новую папку, то тоже используется write.
`ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w').write("somefile", "directory to create\\somefile")` и дальше если нужна пустая папка, удаляете созданный файл.

Comment: мне нужно именно папку архивировать а не файл

Comment: @htmlпрограммист Я изменил ответ. Подходит ли вам новая версия?

Comment: мне именно нужно архивировать папку где хранятся файлы, а не создание папки